# How do I make a snap scrolling picker on react web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make a similar kind of picker what normally have in mobile app alerm clock like android or ios, but on web using React. But I am unable to get the selected value.

```css
.picker {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 2ch;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.picker::before,
.picker::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    hsl(200 20% 10%), 
    65%,
    hsl(200 20% 10% / 0%)
  );
  /*   backdrop-filter: blur(1px); */
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(50% - 3.5ex);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.picker::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    hsl(200 20% 10% / 0%), 
    35%, 
    hsl(200 20% 10%)
  ); 
}

.picker > * {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 9vmin;
  align-items: center;
  max-block-size: calc(9vmin * 5);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  padding-inline-end: 1ch;
  font-size: 7vmin;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: hsl(0 0% 20%);
}

.picker > [title]::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: start;
  color: hsl(0 0% 65%);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: min(.5em, 40%);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsl(0 0% 0% / 50%);
}

.picker > [title]:first-child::before {
  text-align: end;
}

.picker > * > * {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}


time, span {
  color: hsl(200 20% 80%);
  text-align: center;
}

html {
  block-size: 100%;
  inline-size: 100%;
  background: hsl(200 20% 10%);
}

body {
  min-block-size: 100%;
  min-inline-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="picker">
  <span title="Sports">
    <span>Cricket</span>
    <span>Football</span>
    <span>Hocky</span>
    <span>Rugby</span>
    <span>Carrom</span>
    <span>Ludu</span>
    <span>Kabadi</span>
    <span>Other</span>
  </span>
  <span title="Instructor">
   <span>Rakib</span>
   <span>Sakib</span>
   <span>Jodu</span>
   <span>Modhu</span>
    <span>Ram </span>
    <span>Shyam</span>
    <span>Hasan</span>
    <span>Arun</span>
    <span>Habib</span>
    <span>Tamim</span>
  </span>
  <span title="Vanue">
    <span>Sylhet</span>
    <span>Dhaka</span>
    <span>Khulna</span>
    <span>Chittagong</span>
    <span>Sunamganj</span>
    <span>Noakhali</span>
    <span>Khagrachori</span>
    <span>Thakurgaong</span>
    <span>Andaman</span>
    <span>Sydny</span>
    <span>London</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the codepan link
[CodePan](https://codepen.io/mjahmedwd/pen/wvjbZjR)

Can you add js to the file so that I can get the selected value, and later convert it to React? Or is there any scroll picker package available for React which I was unable to find.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use an `<input type="date">` element and handle the selection changes via an `onChange` event listener. Currently without using an input element, you'd have to grab the current "selection" in a hacky way.

Comment: That is exactly what I need, In my case this is a date, but this scrollable picker can be a list of names also. so how do I do this? please run the snippet or go to the codepen to get a clear idea about my query

Comment: updated the code so that none gets confused with dates